# how to get rid of the header and footer when printing from a web browser?

Tags: javascript, printing, printf

I am using the function on window print to print from within my web application.

```
`<body onload=""window.print();"">
```

But on the header i get the date `07/10/2011`and page title and footer i get the url of the page. How do i remove these? and i get `1/1` or `1/2 2/2` etc

I am redirecting users to a page and generating the page dynamically and just want what is being generated to print.

I just want the content so i can put it on headed paper,

with out the extras?

Comment: This is controlled by the individual browser, and not something you can change. If you want that sort of control you'd have to make a PDF or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser settings. JavaScript does not control this.

Comment: any idea in the settings what i change?

Comment: I'm not going to guess the version for you.